# How can I backup VimWiki on Git

Tags: autocmd, plugin-vimwiki

I'll start by saying that I never wrote any VimScript or done any advanced configuration in my `.vimrc`. I'm a super noob . Bear with me.

I've been trying to backup my [VimWiki](https://vimwiki.github.io/) on Git. I want to add some redundancy to the Dropbox setup already in place.

I've been following the instructions [here](https://dmoerner.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/vimwiki-and-git-autocommit/):

```
augroup vimwiki
au! BufWritePost ~/vimwiki/* !git add "%";git commit -m "Auto commit of %:t." "%"
augroup END
```

For my first test, I saved the wiki index. I got this error:

```
!git add "/Users/gio/Dropbox/vimwiki/markdown/index.md"
fatal: /Users/gio/Dropbox/vimwiki/markdown/index.md: 
  '/Users/gio/Dropbox/vimwiki/markdown/index.md' is outside repository  at '/Users/gio/dotfiles'
```

Where `/Users/gio/dotfiles` is the folder from where I opened Vim.

If I `cd` to `/Users/gio/Dropbox/vimwiki`, saving the file results in the commit. But that's annoying, I'd like to be able to open the wiki from anywhere and commit and push the changes on every save.

I tried to add a `pushd` and `popd` to the mix, like this:

```
" Backup on Git
function CommitChangeInWiki()
  !pushd ~/Dropbox/vimwiki
  !git add "%"
  !git commit -m "Auto commit of %:t." "%"
  !popd
endfunction

au! BufWritePost ~/Dropbox/vimwiki/**/* call CommitChangeInWiki()
```

It doesn't work, though. I can see that `pushd` is called.

I'm clearly missing something here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ben already gave a good answer. Anyway: In Vim you can use `:cd <path>` and `:cd -` to jump back.

Comment: Welcome, _super noob_!   :D :D

Comment: Do let the person who answered know if their post helped (by accepting and/or voting) or not (by providing further details). https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pushd` won’t work because it happens in a temporary shell. You could use `cd && ...`, but the best (I think) is `git -C dir command`, which makes git run in the provided directory.

Comment: Thank you [@D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble). It took me a while to reply to you because I was experimenting this setup on my spare setup... Anyways, this works thank you :) One thing I'm not sure about is that it worked in the `function` syntax, but not in one liner one.